# Can't connect to a remote host with virt-manager

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, remote-access, linux-kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to connect from a laptop (computer1) to a host (remote1).
On computer1 I have user1 on the host I have a different user (user2).
Both systems are running Debian, the remote1 system is a clean install of Debian Buster.

The error I'm receiving is the following:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.

End of file while reading data: sh: 1: nc: not found: Input/output error

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running
on the remote host.

Libvirt URI is: qemu+ssh://user2@172.25.230.57/system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 904, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 148, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: End of file while reading data: sh: 1: nc: not found: Input/output error
```

I can ssh with user 1 from computer 1 to remote1 with:

```
user1@computer1:~$ ssh user2@172.25.230.57
```

and I'm prompted with a password request.
I also tried setting up passwordless login using private-public key and that works simply ssh-ing but trying virt-manager I get the error.

As soon as I try:

```
user1@computer1:~$ virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://user2@172.25.230.57/system'
```

I get the error.

As it doesn't matter if I'm using public key or password authentication (I get the error in both scenarios) I reverted back to password authentication.

On remote1 I only have the following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Port 22
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

In /var/log/auth.log I can't seem to find a failed authentication.

Any idea/suggetion on what this is and why?

```
End of file while reading data: sh: 1: nc: not found: Input/output error
```

I'm new to Linux and sys-admin so after 3 days of tries and constant googling I'm at a loss.

Comment: I *totally* don't know how `virt-manager` works under the hood, yet `nc: not found` *suggests* something tries to use `nc` and the executable cannot be found. If the setup really misses `nc` then try to add (install) it. Where? I don't know because it's not clear for me if `nc: not found` comes from the local or the remote system. Ensuring `nc` is available on both ends seems a good strategy. Also keep in mind [there are at least two implementations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368160/108618); it's not clear which one is preferred or strictly required. *Maybe* it will work with any.

Answer (score 1):

After insuring that the libvirtd daemon is indeed running, install nc (netcat) on the server to fix this error, as Kamil surmised in the comment above.

I was given the option of gnu-netcat or openbsd-netcat on Arch Linux and had to use the openbsd version, since the gnu version apparently does not support the '-U' option, which virt-manager appears to require.

Thanks to Kamil for putting me on track to solve this exact issue!